# Java - code won't transform dog age in human years

Tags: java, calculator, converters

I am trying to do a program that will convert the input age of a dog into human years, but it doesn't work. Here are the instructions I had for the conversion of the dog years to human years: 
A method *inHumanYears* which will return the age of a pet dog in human years. Here is how to calculate it:

- 15 human years equals the first year of a medium-sized dog's life.
- Year two for a dog equals about nine years for a human.
- And after that, each human year would be approximately five years for a dog.

Here a few examples:

- a 4-month old dog = 0.25 (which is 1/4 of a year)*15 = 3.75 human years
- a 5 years old = 15+9+(5-2) * 5 = 39 human years

So here is what my code looks so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyPet_1_lab7 {
    // Implement the class MyPet_1 so that it contains 3 instance variables
        private String breed;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private double inHumanYears;

    // Default constructor
        public MyPet_1_lab7()
        {
            this.breed = null;
            this.name = null;
            this.age = 0;
        }
    // Constructor with 3 parameters
        public MyPet_1_lab7(String a_breed, String a_name, int an_age){
            this.breed = a_breed;
            this.name = a_name;
            this.age = an_age;
            this.inHumanYears = inHumanYears();
        }
    // Accessor methods for each instance variable
        public String getBreed(){
            return this.breed;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public int getAge(){
            return this.age;
        }
    //Mutator methods for each instance variable
        public void setBreed(String a_breed){
            this.breed = a_breed;
        }
        public void setName(String a_name){
            this.name = a_name;
        }
        public void setAge(int an_age){
            this.age = an_age;
            this.inHumanYears = inHumanYears();
        }
    // toString method that will return the data in an object formated as per the output
        public String toString(){
            return (this.breed + " whose name is " + this.name + " and " + (double)this.age + " dog years (" + inHumanYears() + " human years old)");
        }
        public boolean equals(MyPet_1_lab7 a){
            if ((this.breed.equals(a.getBreed())) && (this.age == a.getAge())){
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        public double inHumanYears(){
            if ((double)age >= 2 ){
                inHumanYears = (15 + 9 + (age - 2))*5;
                return (inHumanYears);
                }
            else {
                inHumanYears = age*15;
                return (inHumanYears);
            }
        }
        public double getHumanYears(){
            double yearOneAge = age >=1 ? 1.0: age;
            double yearTwoAge = age >=2 ? 1.0: age > 1? age-1.0: 0.0;
            double yearThreeAge = age > 2 ? age-2.0: 0.0;

            inHumanYears = yearOneAge * 15 + yearTwoAge*9 + yearThreeAge * 5;
            return inHumanYears;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("What type of dog do you have? ");
        String breed = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("What is its name? ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How old? ");
        int age = keyboard.nextInt();
        MyPet_1_lab7 dog= new MyPet_1_lab7();
        System.out.println(dog);
        MyPet_1_lab7 dog1 = new MyPet_1_lab7(breed,name,age);
        System.out.println(dog1);



    }

}
'''
```

Comment: Can you be more precise as to in what way(s) it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Also, is `age` in months or in years? How are you calling this (what values)? And are breed and name relevant to your question?

Comment: Hint: you'd probably want to use a `double` or `float` instead of an `int`.

Comment: It prints out like this for example : German Sheperd whose name is Casey and 2 dog years (0.0 human years old)

Comment: @Elliott Frisch age is in years, breed and name is not relevant to my question, and what do you mean with "how are you calling this (what values)"?

Comment: Your method inHumanYears is never called

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen My instance variable age has to be an int, that is what is written in my instructions

Comment: @PaulRooney I know it sound weird but that is what my teacher gave me

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean I never called inHumanYears? I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: In that case, you want to convert to a `float` or `double` before dividing. In Java `11 / 12 = 0`

Comment: See also [Integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I am not sure to understand what you mean with 11/12 = 0?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I am not sure where to put it in my code?

Comment: Ok, so it prints out the result of the transformation from dog years to human years as a double. But now it doesn't print out the correct result for the transformation. If I put 4 years (in dog years) it gives me 130 human years instead of 34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thank you everybody for your time and your help. So here is what I did, I changed the private int age to a double. My friend told me that we didn't need to necessarily put it to an integer. The rest was just change everything to double and it solved all my problem for my output:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyPet_1_lab7 {
    // Implement the class MyPet_1 so that it contains 3 instance variables
        private String breed;
        private String name;
        private double age; // instead of private int age;

        MyPet_1_lab7 dog1;
        MyPet_1_lab7 dog2;

    // Default constructor
        public MyPet_1_lab7()
        {
            this.breed = null;
            this.name = null;
            this.age = 0;
        }
    // Constructor with 3 parameters
        public MyPet_1_lab7(String a_breed, String a_name, double an_age){
            this.breed = a_breed;
            this.name = a_name;
            this.age = an_age;
        }
    // Accessor methods for each instance variable
        public String getBreed(){
            return this.breed;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public double getAge(){
            return this.age;
        }
    //Mutator methods for each instance variable
        public void setBreed(String breed2){
            this.breed = breed2;
        }
        public void setName(String name2){
            this.name = name2;
        }
        public void setAge(double age2){
            this.age = age2;
        }
    // toString method that will return the data in an object formated as per the output
        public String toString(){
            return (this.breed + " whose name is " + this.name + " and " + this.age + " dog years (" + inHumanYears() + " human years old)");
        }
        public boolean equals(MyPet_1_lab7 a){
            if ((this.breed.equals(a.getBreed())) && (this.age == a.getAge())){
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        double human_age = 0;
        public double inHumanYears(){
            if (this.age < 1)
                human_age = (this.age) * 15;
            if (this.age >=1 && this.age < 2)
                human_age = 15 + (this.age - 1) * 9;
            if (this.age >= 2 ){
                human_age = 15 + 9 + (age - 2)*5;
                }

            return human_age;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("What type of dog do you have? ");
        String breed = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("What is its name? ");
        String name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How old? ");
        double age = keyboard.nextDouble();
        MyPet_1_lab7 dog= new MyPet_1_lab7();
        System.out.println(dog);
        MyPet_1_lab7 dog1 = new MyPet_1_lab7(breed,name,age);
        System.out.println(dog1);

        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nLet's set up the 1st dog ... ");
        System.out.print("\tWhat breed is it? ");
        String breed1 = key.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\tWhat is the dog's name? ");
        String name1 = key.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\tHow old is the dog in dog years (a double number)? ");
        double age1 = key.nextDouble();
        MyPet_1_lab7 dog2 = new MyPet_1_lab7 (breed1, name1, age1);
        System.out.println("Dog1 is now a(n) " + dog2);

        System.out.println("\nAre the 2 dogs the same breed and age?");
        if ((breed.equals(breed1))&& age == age1)
            System.out.println("Yes, they are the same breed and age");
        else 
            System.out.println("No, they are not the same breed and/or age");
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your `toString()` method accesses a field you *set* with a method that has not been called. This

```
public String toString(){
    return (this.breed + " whose name is " + this.name + " and " 
            + this.age + " dog years (" + inHumanYears + " human years old)");
}
```

should be changed to invoke `inHumanYears()`. Like,

```
public String toString(){
    return (this.breed + " whose name is " + this.name + " and " 
            + this.age + " dog years (" + inHumanYears() + " human years old)");
}
```

Comment: Looks like he will have a problem with `inHumanYears = (age/12)*15;`

Comment: @ScaryWombat, you are write, I am having a problem with that, it gives me 120 years in human years. But it works :)

Comment: @Jennifer See the link I gave you in the top comments

Answer (score 0):

Your method InHumanYears() is never called + your attribute inHumanYears is never assigned.

You must change your second constructor.

Before :

```
 public MyPet_1_lab7(String a_breed, String a_name, int an_age){
        this.breed = a_breed;
        this.name = a_name;
        this.age = an_age;
    }
```

After :

```
public MyPet_1_lab7(String a_breed, String a_name, int an_age){
        this.breed = a_breed;
        this.name = a_name;
        this.age = an_age;
        this.inHumanYears = inHumanYears();
    }
```

You must also called inHumanYears() in setAge() :

```
setAge(int age){
  this.age = age;
  this.inHumanYears = inHumanYears();
}
```

I obtain this execution (I think your calculation is incorrect):

> toto whose name is tata and 3 dog years (125.0 human years old)

Comment: Thanks, I am able to print it out, but the calculation is wrong, I am not sure how to solve it

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the `inHumanYears` is only going to be updated in the constructor.  If `setAge` is called later, the result will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your algo seems wrong for the stated requirements.

1. 15 human years equals the first year of a medium-sized dog's life.
2. Year two for a dog equals about nine years for a human.
3. And after that, each human year would be approximately five years
   for a dog.

also you should change age to allow for decimal points. (if not age may be in  months, like the example for your 4month old dog -> in which case you should divide everything by 12). It's usually better to name it ageMonth or ageYear to remove that ambiguity.

you can try breaking each component down.

note:  the ?: are [ternary operators](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html). Think of it as a "short form" for the if-else statement

```
public double getHumanYears(){


    double yearOneAge = age>=1 ? 1.0: age;
//if age>1, then year1Age=1, otherwise year1Age = age

    double yearTwoAge = age>=2 ? 1.0: age>1? age-1.0: 0.0;
//if age>2, then year2Age=2, elseIf age>1, then year2Age = age-1, otherwise, year2Age is 0.

    double yearThreeAge = age>2 ? age-2.0: 0.0;
//if age>2, then year3Age= age-2, otherwise, year3Age is 0.

//the formula will break down an age into 3 parts.
//yearOneAge: from 0.0 to 1.0. 
//yearTwoAge: from 0.0 to 1.0. 
//yearThreeAge: from 0.0 onwards. 
//e.g. age=0.8years, year1=0.8, year2=0.0, year3=0.0
//e.g. age=1.5years, year1=1.0, year2=0.5, year3=0.0
//e.g. age=3.6years, year1=1.0, year2=1.0, year3=1.6

    inHumanYears = yearOneAge * 15 + yearTwoAge * 9 + yearThreeAge * 5
    return inHumanYears; 

}
```

also like Quentin said, you forgot to call getHumanYears in your setter and constructor, or you can update the toString to call getHumanYears().

Comment: Ok, so the code you are givin me is going to call the getHumanYears? I don't understand what it does

Comment: @Jennifer, i added some comments in the codes, you can see if it helps.